# How to make angular project work that's downloaded from github?

Tags: angular

I have this github link
https://github.com/jackfiallos/HotelManagementSystem/tree/master/client

i tried to start it via npm install then ng serve but it says 
"The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."?

Comment: That's because the project is targeted to use old version of angular cli, as you can see it has `angular-cli.json` and what you most likely have is the newer angular cli that uses `angular.json`.

Comment: @penleychan yeah it uses version 1.4.9 that is written in the github readme but when i open the package.json there is another version "@angular/cli": "^7.3.4", in devDependencies field this means when ever i make npm install it will upgrade the angular

Comment: How did you install it? npm i?

Comment: try to downgrade you `@angular/cli` prior to running `ng serve`: `npm i @angular/cli@1.4.9 -D` and than `node_modules/.bin/ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

Check your project Path on the terminal/command window where you are hitting the command

> npm install

. There will be your project path on terminal something like c://user/download/Angular_project

Answer (score 0):

1. open terminal and set path to the folder of the project
2. use command

   ```
   $ npm i
   ```
3. use command

   ```
   $ ng serve
   ```